# How to split String by taking space's in java

Tags: java, string

I know its very easy to split data in strings, but still i want guide to concate string,
my data is in the format. In my string the data is in the above format

```
104
inNetStandardGuest
windowsGuest
uestToolsTooOld


121
slesGuest
guestToolsTooOld
20569355609
```

Expected Output:

```
104,inNetStandardGuest,windowsGuest,uestToolsTooOld
121,slesGuest,guestToolsTooOld,20569355609
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Guava's [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) and [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html):

```
final Iterable<String> lines = Splitter.on("\n\n\n").split(input);
for (final String line : lines) {
  final Iterable<String> fields = Splitter.on("\n").split(line);
  final String joined = Joiner.on(",").join(fields);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's simply splitting and combining strings.

```
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
for (String set : data.split("\n\n\n")) {
    for (String line : set.split("\n")) {
        out.append(line).append(',');
    }
    out.setCharAt(out.length(), '\n');
}
System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: +1 for use of `StringBuilder`, but you can also use `out.setCharAt(out.length(), '\n');` (and remove `deleteCharAt` line)

Comment: If you used `"\n\n+"` for the outer pattern, any number of empty lines  would separate two blocks.

Comment: True, but no reason to check for that if the data format is unchanging.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
String s = "104\n" +
           "inNetStandardGuest\n" +
           "windowsGuest\n" +
           "uestToolsTooOld\n" +
           "\n" +
           "\n" +
           "121\n" +
           "slesGuest\n" +
           "guestToolsTooOld\n" +
           "20569355609\n";

System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(.)\\n","$1,")
                    .replaceAll(",,","\n")
                    .replaceAll(",\\n","\n"));
```

Probably not the most efficient way, though.

Answer (score 0):

Buffered reader:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

readLine() method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

For example you read 4 lines

```
  string outputLine = line1 + "," + line2 + "," + line3 + "," + line4;
```

Then read 2 lines and skip it.

If you don't know how to implement it using my advices, you should read
some basics tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String str = "104\ninNetStandardGuest\nwindowsGuest\nuestToolsTooOld\n\n\n121\nslesGuest\nguestToolsTooOld\n20569355609";
str= str.replaceAll("\\s", ",").replaceAll(",,,", "\n");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output :

```
104,inNetStandardGuest,windowsGuest,uestToolsTooOld
121,slesGuest,guestToolsTooOld,20569355609
```